# Calling a function while having local variables

Tags: assembly

I have a function which has some local variables and it calls a different function which accepts two arguments. I'm new to assembly and i'm not sure if the local variables will screw up my stack for the new function. Aren't they technically on the stack just as the values of 1 and 2 are which I push later later on? Do I have to save the locals somewhere else and add esp, 4 and then push the values of 1 and 2, getting rid of the locals from the stack?

```
my_function:
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 4
mov dword [ebp - 4], 10
push dword ptr 1
push dword ptr 2
call other_function
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
```

Comment: Yes, they are on the stack, and no, they won't screw up your called function because they are further away than the arguments.

Comment: So can other_function technically access my local variables from my_function?

Comment: @BobBobby Yes, indeed.

Comment: Aren't the local variables specific to the function since they don't directly modify esp when placed but rather the copy at ebp?

Comment: the other function can in the sense that if it goes outside its stack space (which is easy in assembly) access yours and anyone elses stack data.  They could access esp + 100 and wander about through some other functions data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is the whole idea of a stack, these local items are pushed onto the stack the stack pointer is moved to make room for them, the next function that address for the stack pointer is where they start putting stuff on the stack.  and on and on.  when a function cleans up it puts the stack pointer exactly where it found it, so the prior person doesnt see it change, they can reference their internal things, then they put it back.

So if function A adds 3 things, calls function B that adds 1 thing, calls function C that adds 4 things, then function C cleans up four things and returns.  B cleans up 1 thing and returns.  A cleans up 3 things and returns.

Adding things to the stack can be a simple math modification of the stack pointer (subtract 4) or it could be individual push instructions (whatever the instruction set uses for that).  Likewise on the return depending on what you want to do with that stack data you can simply modify the pointer to put it back or you can pop things, say registers you wanted to preserve the prior state of during the function (and all of its siblings).

So for example take this carefully crafted function

```
unsigned int more_fun (unsigned int x, unsigned int y);
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int x, unsigned int y )
{
    return(x+(y<<more_fun(x+3,y+4)));
}
```

And let the compiler deal with it.

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e92d4070    push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
   4:   e1a04000    mov r4, r0
   8:   e1a05001    mov r5, r1
   c:   e2800003    add r0, r0, #3
  10:   e2811004    add r1, r1, #4
  14:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <more_fun>
  18:   e0840015    add r0, r4, r5, lsl r0
  1c:   e8bd4070    pop {r4, r5, r6, lr}
  20:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

So true, I dont have any local variables per se, but I have made it such that the incoming parameters want to survive the call to the nested function.  We also have to save our return address (intentionally used a different instruction set, this one is really easy to read anyway).

So in this instruction set our return address in is r14 or lr (link register) our first parameter comes in in r0, our second parameter comes in in r1, and our return goes back in r0.

So they could have saved the two parameters on the stack but for performance they saved two other registers on the stack (that are not going to be destroyed by the next function per the calling convention here) and saved our input parameters in those registers for the duration of this function.

The return address has to be preserved as well so we know how to return from fun, the call to more_fun will put the return to fun address in it so we have to save lr before we call.  This convention insists on the stack being 64 bit aligned so r6 is used strictly for that purpose to make the stack aligned, it does not need to be preserved otherwise.

We setup and call the function.  We get the return value in r0, we prepare to return by doing the last bit of math, and then take all the items we put on the stack and take them off. And then return.

To align the stack it could have pushed r4,r5 and lr, then did an sp=sp-4 then on the return do an sp=sp+4 then popped the three registers but that is less efficient.

So if when entering this function the stack pointer was at 0x1000, then after the push the stack pointer is at 0x0FF0 (4 items, 4 bytes each, taht is 16 bytes or 0x10), so when more_fun is entered sp is 0xFF0 if it pushe stuff then the stack pointer adjusts, when it returns it needs to make sure sp is 0xFF0 so that we can then pop off our four items and get the right four items, and then we return with the sp set to 0x1000.

When we return, the four values are still in memory between 0xFF0 and 0x1000, but that is fine the next function called or at least some function down the road will write over those with its local data.

Do you have to save the locals somewhere else?  No the stack is the right place, or as the compiler has done it here, the right amount of data needs to be saved to the stack so that your other parameters can be saved.  This was an optimization, unioptimized the incoming parameters would be saved to locations on the stack "allocated" by this function (either by pushes or by math on the stack pointer) and then if those items need to read later they can be read from the stack, if they need to be preserved during a call, they are already there preserved on the stack.

Comment: So does that mean that my other_function can still access my local variables created in my_function simply by accessing esp - X?

Comment: esp + X but yes (for a downward growning stack, downward meaning the address becomes a smaller number when you push things on the stack)

Comment: functions that called you can use esp - X so long as they do it before some other function overwrites that data

Comment: Ok I understand now. So essentially I have to keep track of where the current stack pointer is and where each value/variable is on the stack during long nested function calls and basically at all times in order to be able to use/refer to it later on?

Comment: Yes, and a stack frame makes that easier, notice how you have ebp and esp, you save ebp, the prior functions stack frame, then you use ebp within your function to references items in your function, you move esp one time at the beginning to allocate that space on the stack for your function and then undo it one time at the end.  This prevents having to keep track all the way through with pushes and pops.

Comment: You can do this without a stack frame pointer, you can just move esp one time at the beginning to make room for everything local in that function, then put it back at the end, for the duration of the function you use esp-X to access items.  With the stack frame pointer ebp it is ebp+X.  six of one, half dozen of another, except you burn another register with one solution.

Comment: the most difficult would be to be pushing and popping things throughout the function your sp-X would vary across the function to access the same item, quite doable, just takes more work and is more error prone.